# CSS :hover on child selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container-s">
    <div class="service">
        <div class="animate-this">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The animate-this class could appear different times throughout the html. so, this is what I've come up with

```
.container-s .service:hover .container-s .animate-this {

}
```

But this won't work

Can anyone please suggest an alternative way alongside the child selectors?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try removing one of those .container-s from your CSS rule

Comment: @BoltClock i want to use a child selector after `hover`. is it possible?

Comment: That's still not entirely clear. Perhaps give some examples of how "the animate-this class could appear different times throughout the html", and state in plain English what you're trying to do. For example, are you trying to animate that element when service is hovered? Where else could that element potentially occur?

Comment: @BoltClock yup, on service `hover`. `animate-this` cud appear on another container say `container-a` which is not part of the services cntainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, because both elements are part of the same container you do not need to specify the same container more than once:

```
.container-s .service:hover .animate-this
```

This finds `.animate-this` within `.service` on hover, itself within `.container-s`. By having the additional `.container-s` there you are saying that `.animate-this` appears within some inner container, which is incorrect. This is not to be confused with grouping several *distinct* selectors using a comma, in which case you will need to repeat the container portion for each selector. In this case, you're only dealing with one selector.

---

If `.animate-this` can appear in a different container than `.service`, then this would only be possible in CSS if you could actually express this relationship using a selector. Unfortunately CSS selectors are very limited in their scope, in particular there is no way to ascend from a container in order to traverse to a completely different element.

Your real objective is to animate this element when `.service` is hovered *regardless of where it appears in the HTML*. This would require using JavaScript to find each element separately, as CSS selectors operate based on concrete relationships between elements.